# How to conditionally get data from 2 streams with rxjs

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I am combining two streams of data:

- The first stream is an array of programs that are returned from an endpoint.
- The second stream is from our state, which is an array of program IDs (what programs are selected).

The problem I am facing is that if the selections stream updates, it automatically re-runs the first stream causing excessive HTTP requests upon each selection change.

I only want `getPrograms` to run initially, to get program data. But I want the selections stream to stay open, so we can get the latest changes from the state.

What operator can i use to achieve this?

```
    this.filteredPrograms$ = combineLatest([this.getPrograms(), this.selectedProgramIdsState$]).pipe(
      map((combined) => {
        const programs = combined[0];
        const selections = combined[1];
        return programs.map((program: ProgramSearchResultModel) => {
          if (program && program.programNumber) {
            program['checked'] = selections.includes(program.programNumber);
          }
          this.dashboardService.resetPagination = false;
          return program;
        });
      })
    );
```

- `getPrograms()` returns an observable of programs[]
- `selectedProgramIdsState$` returns an observable of string[]

Comment: could you please add code related to `getPrograms()` and `selectedPropgramIdsState$`? Better yet, could you provide a reproducible example? (like a stacklitz or a git repo)

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz at the end of my question I mention what the return values are of each

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the `withLatestFrom` operator.

Assuming you have the following streams:

1. `programs$` which emits an HTTP response
2. `selection$` which emits every time a user click on a checkbox

Then `selection$.pipe(withLatestFrom(programs$))` emits an array of the latest values emitted by each stream when `selection$` emits:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlqMFvHwgWJ1vfts5fdC2WzxDaIXWfYuAd9Tb2lobtF61Gk+HIRDrbtxgasBSM9lZgOK9ilwK9LqFIYEV+k0IA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<fieldset>
<legend>Avail. programs</legend>
<input type="checkbox" id="prog1"/> prog. 1
<input type="checkbox" id="prog2"/> prog. 2
<input type="checkbox" id="prog3"/> prog. 3
<input type="checkbox" id="prog4"/> prog. 4
<input type="checkbox" id="prog5"/> prog. 5
</fieldset>

<p></p>


<script>
const {timer, of, fromEvent} = rxjs;
const {tap, switchMapTo, map, withLatestFrom, scan} = rxjs.operators;


const init$ = timer(2000);


// Simulate a delay between an HTTP request and its response.
const programs$ =
  timer(500).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('requesting programs… ✓')),
    switchMapTo(of({ prog1: 'Natural Language Processing'
                   , prog2: 'Machine learning'
                   , prog3: 'Computational geometry'
                   , prog4: 'Computational linguistics'
                   , prog5: 'Formal methods'})));
                   
                   
const selection$ =
  fromEvent(document.querySelector('fieldset'), 'input').pipe(
    map(({target: {id, checked}}) => ({id, checked})),
    scan((acc, {id, checked}) => ({...acc, [id]: checked}), {}),
    withLatestFrom(programs$));

selection$.subscribe(([sels, programs]) => {
  document.querySelector('p').textContent =
    Object.entries(sels)
          .filter(([, checked]) => checked)
          .map(([id]) => programs[id])
          .join(', ');
});

</script>
```